# Is there a way to restrict the external users to access my server files

Tags: security, file, .htaccess, authorization

Is there a way to restrict the external users to access my server files..

example is when i access this dir http://puptaguig.net/evaluation/js/ it shows the 404 page(though it's not obvious) but when i tried to view control.js here http://puptaguig.net/evaluation/js/controls.js it opened up..

```
   IndexIgnore *
   <Files .htaccess>
   order allow,deny
   deny from all
   </Files>
```

i just want to make these files inside my server directory to secured from outside viewing for some reasons..but how?

Best Regards..

Comment: If you block access co js, images and css files then they wont be available at all for the website. Is that what you want? Or do you simply wàntto block files that are not necessary for your website?

Comment: From what I can tell controls.js gives a 404 as well ...

Comment: Considering that you copied significant portions of your controls.js code, I don't think trying hide it is ethical.

Answer (score 1):

siegheil/js? Should be siegheil/ns for sure?

You could chmod 000 and then no one would see them or access them. You can't have people accessing and not seeing them at the same time. Can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can add below lines to your `httpd.conf or. htaccess` this will avoid access of your `JavaScripts`

```
<Files ~ "\.js$">
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all   
 Satisfy All     
</Files>
```

Comment: The `Satisfy` is useless in this context, as that is only used whenever both `Allow` and `Require` are used in the same section. Also see the [official Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#Satisfy) on this directive. Other than that, this answer is good, should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think to manage this is deny access to your js files by throwing a .htaccess in the `siegheil/js/` folder that says something along the lines of:

```
deny from all
```

or just simply put your code in a folder above the root document level of the site itself.

After that, you then use something like [minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) to retrieve the js files from the backend (PHP / some other server language side) and have the minified / obfuscated code placed in another folder or just outputted directly from the script.

With all that said, in the end, the js code must be downloaded one way or another to be run by the browser. This will make it impossible to prevent people from looking at your code and figuring out what it does if they *really* want to.

Answer (score 1):

You were able to access `http://puptaguig.net/evaluation/js/controls.js` but not   `http://puptaguig.net/evaluation/js/` because most Apache installs prevent an anonymous user from viewing the directory contents, and only permit access to specific files in the directory.

There is no way "hide" client-side JS because without access to those files your users will not be able to run your script. As suggested by @General Redneck, you can obfuscate and minify your js using a tools like minify or [uglifyJS](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs), but those can, potentially, been un-minified (minification is still a good idea for performance reasons). Ultimately you are fighting against the "open" nature of the web. I'd suggest putting a license on your code, and keeping an open mind : )

If you **really** need something to be secure, try accomplishing the essential functionality (which you want to keep private) with a backend language like `php` or `asp.net` and feeding the relevant data to you JS script.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an .htaccess file in the relevant directory that has

```
-Indexes
```

in it. This will prevent listing of the directory and will cause a 403 error to be raised. Your application can then handle that however it wants to display whatever you want.